# What's new (and useful) in ArcGIS 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-platform

I've just got access to ArcGIS 10 through my university, and it seems to be far nicer than ArcGIS 9.3. I'm trying to find out what exactly has changed, but the ESRI pages on 'What's new in ArcGIS' seem very vague and marketing-oriented.

So, what have you noticed that's different in ArcGIS 10 (preferably useful too)? If possible I'd like to particularly focus on things that maybe aren't obvious, but are very useful and really improve your GIS workflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you have been looking at the wrong sections on the ESRI website?
The web-helps are written by technical writers and are aimed at the people actually using the software.

It was re-branded from 9.4 to 10 due to the major new functionality within ArcGIS Desktop.
Check the web-help section [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_what_s_new_in_ArcGIS_10/00qp0000000p000000/)

There are also a few new features in server which are also outlined in the web-help [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/What_s_new_in_ArcGIS_Server_10/00930000000m000000/).  The APIs are also updated to consume the new functionality with Server, and these can be accessed through [this top-level page](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/web/web-apis).

I personally think that the ESRI UK sub-site on v10 is also a very good one for checking out whats new at v10, which can be seen [here](http://www.esriuk.com/arcgis10/)

I really think that they have done a good job in outlining the new functionality at all of the above links and it would not do the new release justice if I were to attempt to summarise it up myself.

Comment: Yes agree with the ESRI (UK) site has vastly improved, it use to just link to the esri.com site

Answer (score 6):

I recently took these online courses. They are free, and do a decent job of explaining some of the new features with hands on exercises.

[Using ArcMap in ArcGIS Desktop 10](http://training.esri.com/acb2000/showdetl.cfm?DID=6&Product_ID=969)

[Getting Started with GIS (for ArcGIS 10)](http://training.esri.com/acb2000/showdetl.cfm?DID=6&Product_ID=976)

[Editing in ArcGIS Desktop 10](http://training.esri.com/acb2000/showdetl.cfm?DID=6&Product_ID=975)

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap....

When you edit you now get a dialog window for creating features. Just click on the feature type you want, and start creating new features. It's great if you are editing a data set with many different types of features.

GeoProcessing drop down menu options - some of the most common tools are now available in the drop down menu, instead of being buried in ArcToolbox.

Data driven pages (under Cartography tools in ArcToolbox) make it easier to produce map books.

Table of Contents - I like how you can easily set a selectable layer when you are on the view by selection tab, although I wish they had consolidated this into the other tabs.

One new feature I do not like is how attribute tables are no longer displayed as an individual window. The new method is awful for multiple tables....

Answer (score 0):

The Full workings of ArcGIS 10. 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_what_s_new_in_ArcGIS_10/00qp0000000p000000/